# What is the best way to set links so that they auto-update when creating new site from site template?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, hyperlink, links

I'm using SharePoint Online currently and was previously a SP Site Designer/Site Collection Admin for a series of enterprise-edition SP 2003, 2010, and 2013 sites.  I distinctly remember setting up web parts with text and links to things within that site.  Then, when I created a Site Template, and created a new site based on that Site Template, those links auto-updated to the new site's breadcrumb.  It is not working for me in SharePoint online.  Is there a trick to it that I'm forgetting?  Like I remember cutting off part of the link before /sites/etc/etc/etc, but I can't remember if that's what helped.  Any ideas?

Comment: Normally you want to put a relative URL instead of the whole `http(s)://...`. I know for OnPrem having relative URLs make links update automatically if you change site/etc.

Comment: as per my knowledge, with SPO you need a 3rd party tool (like Collaboration Manager); there are quite a few limitations you will encounter in SPO.